# jQuery Grids that bind to JSON

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have seen a couple of great jQuery grids out there such as FlexiGrid and jQGrid..

Both of these seem to require that you bind them to a webservice. Can anyone suggest a grid that is like these but does not require a web server? I have JSON that is generated by my application and I want to bind a grid to it. No need for a server to perform AJAX requests to.

Thanks!

Comment: The data is JSON that is generated as the user interacts with the application. I wish to represent this data in a grid. Requiring that I interact with a server assumes that I am persisting this data in a datastore of some kind (most likely a DB). This is not always the case.

Comment: The application is written in JS.. I have no need to "get it to a frontend". The client browser is the "frontend". No point being.. I don't need a web server I need to display JSON in a grid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [DataTables.net](http://www.datatables.net).  They even have an example on how to bind to a [JS array](http://datatables.net/examples/data_sources/js_array.html), which isn't exactly JSON but lets you bind to an offline datasource.

I've used this plugin quite a bit in my projects in the traditional manner, and I've found it to be pretty fast and quite extensible.